# Error in Stack Snippets console has incorrect lineno and colno

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When there is an error in the JavaScript code in a Stack Snippet:

```js
asoidf
```

I find the error message quite unhelpful.

> Error: {
>   "message": "ReferenceError: asoidf is not defined",
>   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>   "lineno": 13,
>   "colno": 9
>   }

`lineno` is apparently 13 which must be referring to something other than the code I entered in the JavaScript box, because there aren't even 2 lines there... `colno` also seems to be referring to the wrong col when the error is bracket related. This kind of defeats the purpose of having a `lineno` and `colno` in the error message in the first place...

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the rendered HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script><style type="text/css">.as-console-wrapper { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; border-top: 1px solid #000; display: none; }
.as-console { background: #e9e9e9; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: table; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
.as-console-row { display: table-row; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; }
.as-console-row:after { display: table-cell; padding: 3px 6px; color: rgba(0,0,0,.35); border: 1px solid #ccc; content: attr(data-date); vertical-align: top; }
.as-console-row + .as-console-row > * { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; padding: 3px 5px; display: table-cell; font-family: monospace; font-size: 13px; vertical-align: middle; }
.as-console-error:before { content: 'Error: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-assert:before { content: 'Assertion failed: '; color: #f00; }
.as-console-info:before { content: 'Info: '; color: #00f; }
.as-console-warning:before { content: 'Warning: '; color: #e90 }
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-moz-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@-ms-keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
@keyframes flash { 0% { background: rgba(255,240,0,.25); } 100% { background: none; } }
.as-console-row-code, .as-console-row:after { -webkit-animation: flash 1s; -moz-animation: flash 1s; -ms-animation: flash 1s; animation: flash 1s; }</style>
    </head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        asoidf
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper" style="display: block;"><div class="as-console"><div class="as-console-row" data-date="13:33:25.929"><code class="as-console-row-code as-console-error">{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: asoidf is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}</code></div></div></div></body></html>
```

You can see that the `a` is 8 characters from the start of the line. However, it's far from 13 lines from the start of the document, so who knows?

Comment: Do not look at the **rendered** markup, but at the one downloaded from the server (i.e the Response to POST /stacksnippets.net/ in your network panel). There you'll see the `asoidf` line is indeed at l13 (1 empty line before Doctype and no `<style>` block after console's script (which will generate this style block).